# What is drand48() default seed in C?

Tags: c, posix, default, seed

I would like to know what the default seed for `drand48()` is, i.e. if I don't explicitly use `srand48()` before calling `drand48()`?

I checked the source code of **glibc 2.23** (the version I am currently using) and I think it is zero, but if someone can verify it, that would be nice.

Comment: This seems an odd question. Why don't you want to call `srand48()`?

Comment: It is not that I don't want to call it. It is that I forgot to do so. Let me explain.

Comment: I have created a program that uses drand48() and I have to run a large number of experiments with different sets of parameters, among which also 5 different random seeds. I run the first set of experiments without explicitly calling srand48() and these took about 2 weeks to complete. Obviously, I need to also keep track of the seeds I used for the experiments (along with the rest of the parameters). So, this is why I need to know the default seed. Obviously, I would prefer to use the results I already got, save 2 weeks of my time and only run 4 more sets of experiments with different seeds.

Comment: @IoannisE.Venetis: that should go into your question, not in comments. Because what really matters to you is not the standard *specification* of `drand48`  but your particular glibc 2.23 implementation

Answer (score 2):

There is no specific value imposed by POSIX and in the contrary it says that one of the initialization functions should be called:

> The `srand48()`, `seed48()`, and `lcong48()` functions are initialization
>   entry points, one of which should be invoked before either `drand48()`,
>   `lrand48()`, or `mrand48()` is called. (Although it is not recommended
>   practice, constant default initializer values shall be supplied
>   automatically if `drand48()`, `lrand48()`, or `mrand48()` is called without
>   a prior call to an initialization entry point.)

More generally, using functions that use a global shared state is not such a good idea. This set of functions has alternatives that received their state as function arguments.

If you don't call any of theses initialization functions, you go with the phrase in parenthesis. It basically says that the internal states should be initialized with defaults. This is not equivalent to call `srand48` with a specific parameter because that function sets the low order bits to the fixed value `0x330`. It could be equivalent to a call to `seed48(0, 0, 0)`, but this is not completely clear. The term *constant default initializer values* could mean that each implementation provides its default values, or that C's default initializers (all bit `0`) should be used.

Comment: Dear Jens, thank you for your answer. I know already all this, I have read the documentation. Please refer to my answer to Kevin to understand why I need to know this information for the specific version of glibc I use.

Comment: Dear Jens, mentioning seed48() solved my issue, as this function returns the previous value of the internal state. I tested and indeed in the case of the glibc version I am using, the initialization is done as if seed48() had been called with its parameter being an array of 3 unsigned shorts, all of them initialized to 0. Indeed this is different than calling srand48() with a parameter of 0, as the low order bits are set to 0x330E in this case, as you already mentioned.

Thanks for your help! You saved me 2 weeks of waiting :-)

Comment: @IoannisE.Venetis, glad to help. Yes, in your particular case this means that your specific run has been done as if you had initialized it with a call to `seed48(0, 0, 0)` and that it should be reproducible with that.